# Unity - animation is not playing even thought animation.IsPlaying() is already returning 'true'

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I tried playing attack animation on my 3d model using Animation.play("Attack") but somehow the animation is not playing, i already checked using Animation.IsPlaying("Attack") and it returned true, so i don't think it's the coding. Here is the code by the way:

```
animation.Play("Attack");
if(animation.IsPlaying("Attack")){
   Debug.Log("Is Attacking");
}
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the animation setting but i don't know what, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the built-in Animation component, open the Inspector and make sure that the "Attack" animation (or any other animations) is properly added under the Animation component.

Refer to: [Unity Docs - Animation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Animation.html)